# Pre populating data in the form during the update in Angular

Tags: angular

I am new to angular and I have a form which allows user to update their information. I want to pre populate the form with the existing information. With the little knowledge that I have, I am pretty sure this has to be inputted into the .ts file of the component, inside the onSubmit(). I've tried to google this, but I'm in need of some more direct guidance.

Updating with comment that this may be done in ngOnInit()....below is my current

```
 ngOnInit(){
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe((paramMap: ParamMap ) => {
       if (paramMap.has('_id'))
         { this.mode = 'Update'; /*request had a parameter _id */ 
           this.id = paramMap.get('_id');}
       else {this.mode = 'Create';
           this.id = null; }
     });
    }
```

-

```
  onSubmit(){
    console.log('You submitted: ' + 
      this.firstName + ' ' + 
      this.lastName + ' ' + 
      this.email + ' ' + 
      this.phone + ' ' + 
      this.street + ' ' + 
      this.city + ' ' + 
      this.state + ' ' + 
      this.zip)

    if(this.mode =='Create')
      this._myService.addDrivers(
        this.firstName, 
        this.lastName, 
        this.email, 
        this.phone, 
        this.street, 
        this.city, 
        this.state, 
        this.zip,
        this.year,
        this.make,
        this.model

        );
    if(this.mode == 'Update')
      this._myService.updateDriver(
        this.id, 
        this.firstName, 
        this.lastName, 
        this.email, 
        this.phone, 
        this.street, 
        this.city, 
        this.state, 
        this.zip,
        this.year,
        this.make,
        this.model);
    this.router.navigate(['/listDrivers']);
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be done in `ngOnInit()`

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.firstName = 'Sam' // get the data from the service
    ...
  }
```

Comment: I was just about to comment if it is in the binding of ngModel

<form (ngSubmit)='onSubmit()' #myForm='ngForm'>
        <mat-form-field appearance='outline'>
            <input matInput placeholder='First Name' id='firstname' [(ngModel)]='firstName' name='firstname'>
        </mat-form-field>

Comment: Thanks, I understand that will hard code the value to 'Sam' but I need to populate the data off the id and bring back the information from the database. I did update with my current ngOnInit()